# Angular: increase counter on long press

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that contains input with two arrow that increments/decrements numbers.

I'd like to increase/decrease the numbers continuously when the user uses a long click, how can i do that?

[image]

**directive:**

```
'use strict';
(function (module) {
    var vlIncrementor = function () {

        return {
            templateUrl: 'assets/angular-client/app/html/common/incrementor/vlIncrementor.html',
            scope: { model: '=ngModel' },
            controller: function ( $scope ) {
                $scope.increment = function (  ) {
                    $scope.model++;
                };

                $scope.decrement = function () {
                    $scope.model--;
                };
            }
        };
    };
    module.directive('vlIncrementor', vlIncrementor);
}(angular.module('html.common')));
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="vl-increment">
    <i class="fa fa-caret-left fa-lg center" ng-class="{disabled: model === 0}" ng-click="decrement()"></i>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model"/>
    <i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-lg center"  ng-click="increment()"></i>
</div>
```

I tried adding a link function with this code, but it didn't work (it incremented by one like a regular click):

```
link: function ( scope , el) {
                $(el ).find('.fa-caret-left').mouseup(function(){
                    clearTimeout(pressTimer)
                    // Clear timeout
                    return false;
                }).mousedown(function(){
                    // Set timeout
                    pressTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
                        scope.$apply( function () {
                            scope.model--; 
                        });
                    },1000);
                    return false;
                });
            }
```

Comment: save the state of the button in a boolean and fire the timeout until the button is up;

Comment: @Hacketo - isn't it what i'm doing in the link function?

Comment: the setTimeout is fired only one time, not `until the mouse is up`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180332/how-can-i-listen-for-a-click-and-hold-in-angularjs).

A possible solution is to use `ng-mousedown` and `ng-mouseup` and use `$interval` to control the counter.