# How to listen for a click-and-hold in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

[In this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25180332/how-can-i-listen-for-a-click-and-hold-in-angularjs), you can find an example in AngularJS.

But how does this work in Angular 2?

Comment: similar concept, you just have to use the plain js functions instead of $interval or $timeout since ng2 no longer needs wrappers around them. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A simple implementation would look like this.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (mousedown)="mousedown()" (mouseup)="mouseup()" (mouseleave)="mouseup()">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: string;
  timeoutHandler: number;

  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular!'
  }
  public mouseup() {
    if (this.timeoutHandler) {
      clearTimeout(this.timeoutHandler);
      this.name = "canceled";
      this.timeoutHandler = null;
    }
  }

  public mousedown() {
    this.timeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => {
      this.name = "has been long pressed"
      this.timeoutHandler = null;
    }, 500);
  }
}
```

It sets a timeout that is canceled if the user clicks away before a set amount of time.

You can find a working plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/msg1VAaBhQoM4l7pqtD4?p=preview).

If what you want is for something to happen on click on hold it's pretty easy to do as well, just swap setTimeout for setInterval.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 (mousedown)="mousedown()" (mouseup)="mouseup()" (mouseleave)="mouseup()">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name: number = 0;
  timeoutHandler;

  constructor() {
    this.name = -1
  }
  public mouseup() {
    if (this.timeoutHandler) {
      clearInterval(this.timeoutHandler);
      this.name = 0;
      this.timeoutHandler = null;
    }
  }

  public mousedown() {
    this.timeoutHandler = setInterval(() => {
      this.name += 1;
    }, 100);
  }
}
```

A working plnkr can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/0gCIECkCeqCAjwygF4AF?p=preview).

Comment: is this enough or do you want the same solution as it is described in the other post? something that keeps happening while the mouse is held?

Comment: I added a click and hold example as well.

Comment: There seem to be a defect on the second example where `timeoutHandler: number` is set to type number.  It gives an error on method `public mousedown()` saying that this.timeoutHandler red squiggly warns with `Time is not assignable to type number` . So to solve this just remove the type `number` on variable declaration and it works like it was designed by @toskv

Comment: @GelSisaed are you using any library that might overwritte the typings of the `setInterval` function? by default it returns a number. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Return_value

Comment: in this case you might be right.  I have an application scaled by jhipster and are suing microservices kafka, docker and elasticSearch, in the front end we are using a bunch of npm packages.  So it is safe to say yes! So in this case, I had to remove the type.  But good point!

Comment: @AGoranov it should work the same on touchscreens, the same events should be firing when tapping stuff. Please let me know if not, I'll look for a solution for that too.

Comment: Does not work for chrome's phone emulator in dev tools

Comment: For touch devices: `(touchstart)="mousedown()" (touchend)="mouseup()"`